# Django / How to get the primary key from a specific field?

Tags: django

Models.py

```
class scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event name', max_length=120)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
```

Let's say I have recorded a scenes with ***name="world"***

In views.py, how can I query the pk from the name field ?

```
from .models import scenes
 scene = scenes.objects.get('what should I put here to get the pk associated with name World ?')
```

When I entered :

```
scene = scenes.objects.get(name='world').pk
```

I got an error :

*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scenes' referenced before assignment*

Comment: `scenes.objects.get(name='world').pk`
or case insensitive: `scenes.objects.get(name__iexact="world").pk`

but if no scences object contains world as name you get an DoesNotExist exception

Comment: `scenes.objects.get(name='world')`?

Comment: @fransua after seeing your edit it seems that you are not importing `scenes` wherever you entered the line or that after that you are using a variable called `scenes`. A good practice is to name your classes in PascalCase https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#316-naming to better identify variables and methods in your code and improve readability

Comment: @mtzd indeed there was something wrong with my name. I have renames scenes with Scenes ans it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to go with that would be to just:

```py
# views.py

from .models import scenes

scene = scenes.objects.get(name="world")
scene_id = scene.pk # This contains the pk of the scene object
```

Django will try to fetch a unique object with `"world"` as a value for the `name` field. With your current code this has an issue:

- Your `name` field is not `unique` so your DB may contain different `scenes` objects with the `"world"` value for the `name` field. This will lead to problems when calling `get`. To solve that you could add `unique=True` when defining the field:

```py
# models.py

class scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event name', max_length=120, unique=True)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
```

This will ensure that your DB won't contain objects with the same name.

Note also that if there's no object with `name` value equal to `"world"` you'll get an error too. Depending on the context you are using this, you should consider [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) or [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Answer (score 1):

see this: [The pk lookup shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut).

The django documentation declares that primary keys have an equivalent, in this case it is `pk`. So if you declared a primary key in your model (let's say we called it `code`) you could access it as `code` or `pk`. This is useful both to apply filters (like the link above) or to obtain a specific attribute.

Now your question is how to obtain the associated primary key from the name of the event, I will show you below some solutions with consequences to how you declared the model.

A. Using `scenes.objects.get()`:
If you use this method you must take into consideration two things:

1. That the search exists, it not exit, it raises `Model.DoesNotExist` exception.
2. That the search return only **1** object,it finds more than one object, it raises a `Model.MultipleObjectsReturned` exception:

please see the [`Queryset get() method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get)

so if we ignore the second thing, the block of code is like this

```py
# we have 1 object with the name `world`

try:
    scene = scenes.objects.get(name="world")
    scene_pk = scene.pk
except scenes.DoesNotExist: 
    print("The Scene does not Exists")
```

but the second you should use [`Queryset filter() method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with other methods like [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#first) or [`last()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#last)

So I recommend you re-make the Model like this:

```py
class scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event name',unique=True, max_length=120)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
```

or using a [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) like pk or unique field if you don't wanna change the id as primary key

```py
class scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event name', max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
```

the slugfield is ideal if you wish to use the name of the event in the URL.